# Redirecting domain keeping the parameters with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect and old domain(a.com) to the new domain (b.com) keeping the parameters in the url.

So if I go to:
www.a.com/page/parameters
should redirect to 
www.b.com/page/parameters

I've tried a bunch of options to no avail.

In all of them if I go to the domain itself (www.a.com) it succesfully redirects to the new one(www.b.com), but when I go to a specific page(www.a.com/page) the old domain stays in place in this case showing a 404 page.

These are the solutions I've already tried:

Option 1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exampleold\.ie$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.examplenew.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Option 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleold\.ie$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examplenew.com/$1 [R=301,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Option 3

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleold.ie
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.examplenew.com/$1 [P] 
</IfModule>
```

Option 4

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exampleold\.ie$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.examplenew.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The website is made in Wordpress

This is the full .htaccess

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /var/sites/b/examplenew.com/public_html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Redirect 301 /testimonial/ab-jan13/ http://www.examplenew.com/
Redirect 301 /homepage_slide/gopro-hero4/ http://www.examplenew.com/
Redirect 301 /product/gopro-hero3-black-edition-surf/ http://www.examplenew.com/
Redirect 301 /contactus.php http://www.examplenew.com/
Redirect 301 /news/mundaka/487 http://www.examplenew.com/blog/


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1old\.ie$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1old.ie$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2old\.ie$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2old.ie$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.examplenew.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
#Gzip 

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript

</ifmodule> 

#End Gzip
```

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess?

Comment: added the full full htaccess anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` rules and keep redirect rules before WP rules.

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /var/sites/b/examplenew.com/public_html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(testimonial/ab-jan13/|homepage_slide/gopro-hero4/|product/gopro-hero3-black-edition-surf/|contactus\.php|news/mundaka/487) http://www.examplenew.com/ [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1old\.ie$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2old\.ie$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.examplenew.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
#Gzip 

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript

</ifmodule>     
#End Gzip
```

I have made some other improvements in your `htaccess`.